# Hibernate Projection on list Field/Attribute and Restricted.in

Tags: java, hibernate

I am have the following product class

```
productClass
productID
name
make
title
colors {1..*}.
```

I'm trying to get

`productID`, `colors` and `name` field only..

I product works for single `attirbute` but `colorList` wasn't retrieve.

and worst of all.. when I have a criteria (restrictions.in) it says sql is not form properly.. missing attribute y1_

A good example will be

[Hibernate criteria with projection not performing query for @OneToMany mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4661919/hibernate-criteria-with-projection-not-performing-query-for-onetomany-mapping?rq=1)

I am trying to get the PAYMENT with expenses intact using project where else he is trying to get some fields in expenses

Comment: Could you show us the Hibernate code you currently have which is failing, and the full error message you're getting?

Comment: if colors is a list, it should be other table.

Comment: yes color is a list and in another table. I can't show the error message due to sensitivity.  but when I use Restriction.in("productID",idList); it will won't work with projection but works without projections.

Answer (score 1):

If you want project any set of attributes for any item of color list, consider use http://github.com/moesio/seimos Here you are an example:

As an example, you can use criteria as follows:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Cat.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.like(“description”, “Pap”)
  .addOrder(Order.asc(“description”);

Criteria subCriteria = criteria.createCriteria("kind", "kind");
subCriteria.add(Restrictions.eq("description", "persa"));

Criteria anotherSubCriteria = subCriteria.createCriteria("anAssociation","anAssociation");
anotherSubCriteria.add(Restrictions.eq("attribute", "anything"));

criteria.setResultTransformer(new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(Cat.class));

criteria.crateAlias(“kind.anAssociation”, “kind_anAssociation”);

criteria.setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
  .add(Projections.alias(Projections.property(“id”), “id”))
  .add(Projections.alias(Projections.property(“kind.id”, “kind.id”))
  .add(Projections.alias(Projections.property(“kind.anAssocation.attribute”, “kind.anAssociation.attribute”))

List cats = criteria.list();
```

But if you want save some code, you can use Seimos and code just

```
Filters filters = new Filters();
filters.add(new Filters(“description”, “Pap”)
  .add(new Filter(“description”))
  .add(new Filter("kind.description", "persa"))
  .add(new Filter("kind.anAssociation.attribute", "anything"));
List<Cat> cats = dao.find(filters);
```

So, consider use http://github.com/moesio/seimos

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, then you can use such query for your purposes:

```
    List<Object[]> results = sess.createCriteria(Category.class, "category")
                .add(Restrictions.in("category.name", new String[]{"Test1", "Test2"}))
                .createAlias("items", "item")
                .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
                        .add(Projections.property("category.id"), "categoryId")
                        .add(Projections.property("category.name"), "categoryName")
                        .add(Projections.property("item.name"))
                        .add(Projections.property("item.initialPrice")))
         .list();
```

It will return the list of Object[] arrays that represents each row of the result.

I don't know sructure of your Color entity and what fields you need from it thats why I posted example for two default entities: Category and Item (their relationship is one-to-many as in your case).

Instead of array you can use List. For example you can define resrictions in above example in such way:

```
 List<String> inRestrictions = new ArrayList<String>();
 inRestrictions.add("Test1");
 inRestrictions.add("Test2");

    ...
    .add(Restrictions.in("category.name", inRestrictions))
    ...
```

**EDIT:**

If you need Product object with list of colors for it then fetch only it. If you define correct mapping then Colors list will be fetched with it (lazily or eagerly).

```
List<Product> results = sess.createCriteria(Product.class)
       .add(Restrictions.in("... necessary restrictions")
       .list()
```

Comment: how do you add the .setResultTransformer(Tranformers.(Product.class)

Comment: You can add ".setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Product.class))" to criteria, but why? You will lose all data fetched from Colors table. And you will get Product object with only few properties set.

Comment: In such case your mapping is wrong. Post it and may be i can help you to fix it.

Comment: all data fetched from Colors table -?? I need the colors at the same time.. everything in a "Product" Object.

Comment: Please, post your entities and mapping for them (if you use xml mapping). And try to explain cleanly what you want to do. Because now I don't understand what do you want.

Comment: I can't this project is sensitive. Anyway I am just trying to get productID, name and colors(color objects). without the other fields(i.e make).. in a product object. The normal projection technique works for single fields with Transformer.aliaseToBean but for colors it won't work. I don't know why

Comment: And it shouldn't work. Because using projections you will have data from two tables that has relationship one-to-many. In your case better to load list of all products (like I wrote in my edit). If you write all mapping info correct then you will get product object that contains the list of colors. If it is not working then the problem is with your one-to-many mapping. I don't know how else can I help you.

Comment: does your return result in Category objects? I notice you did not use Transformer.AliaseToBean(Category.class) too.. It will return result in a flat layer.